# Reading in records of varying length

Tags: r

I have a data set that needed to be rearranged before I could figure out what was in it. Now I need to figure out how to read it in! I want a data frame in the end. Here are two versions of the data. Of course, I want to read in version 1. I am thinking about using a scan function but ending up with a data.frame. How to do?

Data Set Version 1

```
Danville Va 8.5 15 Miami FL 4.55 
16 Cary NC . 12
```

Data Set Version 2

```
Danville Va   8.5  15 
Miami    FL  4.55  16 
Cary     NC   .    12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most efficient way, but this could work for you (be aware of the warnings):
1. Reading everything and putting it in a vector
 2. then reshape it

```
 library(data.table)
 Data<-fread("Nome AK 2.5 15 Miami FL 6.75 
 18 Raleigh NC . 12")
 vec<- c(unlist(colnames(Data)), unlist(Data)) # putting everything into a a vec
 t(matrix(vec,4,3)) # Shaping the data

# [,1]      [,2] [,3]   [,4]
# [1,] "Nome"    "AK" "2.5"  "15"
# [2,] "Miami"   "FL" "6.75" "18"
# [3,] "Raleigh" "NC" "."    "12"
```

Comment: I have another data set that has unequal length and consists of pairs of  text and numeric data. Can this be modified to handle that? I am reading in with d=read.table(paste0(dirdata,"top.txt"),
header = FALSE,  sep=" ",
strip.white = TRUE, 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE

Comment: Create a question and provide data because it is difficult to respond without understanding it well